# How does one show that a median of a triangle can be exactly defined by the length of sides of a traingle?

Tags: geometry

I heard that any median of a triangle can be exactly defined by the length of sides of a triangle, by $$\frac{\sqrt{2k^2+2l^2-m^2}}{2}$$ where $m$ is the length of the side of a triangle does not contain a vertex of a triangle that the median being defined contains.

Why does this hold?

Comment: The three lengths define a triangle upto congruence. Why surprised?

Comment: As a side note, this is Apollonius Theorem, which is a special case of [Stewart's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw triangle $KLM$, where as usual the length of the side opposite $K$ is $k$, and so on.

Draw the line segment $MQ$, where $Q$ is the midpoint of the side $KL$ of length $m$. We want to find the length $x$ of the median $MQ$.

Let $\theta=\angle MQK$. Then  $\angle MQL=\phi=180^\circ-\theta$.

By the Cosine Law for $\triangle MQK$, we have
$$l^2=x^2+\frac{m^2}{4}-(2x)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\cos \theta.$$
By the Cosine Law for $\triangle MQL$, we have
$$k^2=x^2+\frac{m^2}{4}-(2x)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\cos \phi.$$

Add, and use the fact that $\cos\phi=-\cos\theta$. We get very nice cancellation, and obtain
$$k^2+l^2=2x^2+\frac{m^2}{2}.$$
Now solve for $x$.